# Combination lock with continuous attempts

Tags: permutations, combinations

The lock has 4 symbols (A,B,C,D) and the password is 3 symbols long.

Now, the lock does not "rest" after each attempt. So if I enter "ABCD" and the password is "ABC" or "BCD", it would open.

I tried P(n,k) and C(n,k), but I don't think those are the right answer. I was thinking it's probably a mix of both.

Some Googling introduced me to "Hamilton cycle", and "De Bruijn sequence", but I'm not too familiar with those.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** I'm trying to find the minimum number of symbols that allow me to open the lock. And repeated symbols are okay.

Comment: Sorry, what exactly is your question?

Comment: Are you allowed type the same letters like AABC or AAAA?

Comment: @PatrickStevens Sorry, I'll edit the post to clarify, I'm trying to find out the minimum number of combinations to break the lock.

Comment: @OussamaBoussif Yes, you are allowed the same letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking for the most efficient way of typing up combinations into the lock, then we're essentially looking for a sequence which contains all of the possible 3 digit combinations of the numbers 1 to 4.

First of all, there is actually more than one solution to this. In particular its $\frac{4!\cdot4^{3-1}}{4^3}$ sequences altogether. We can also know the length of each sequence, this is given as $4^3$

If you want to find a solution, one way of doing it is to write up all of the combinations of length 3 and drawing out a Hamiltonian cycle, i.e. connect the numbers with lines where the last digit of one overlaps with the first digit of the other. Then we can find a path which visits every node exactly once. Alternatively, we could write out the Euler cycle for $3-1$ and find a path that visits every edge exactly once. If the end of a sequence is the same as the start of the sequence, we can chop it off. It's much easier to see why this works by drawing it out and visualising it. However there are much more efficient algorithms out there to compute solutions. Here's one I did by hand.

A A A B A A C A D A B B A B C A B D A C B A C C A C D A D B A D C A D D B B B C B B D B C C B C D B D C B D D C C C D C D D D

Though one would have to still type in 66 digits in total

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time and writing it out, then explaining it so clearly.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, the de Bruijn sequence $B(k=4, n=3)$ is the most efficient way to check all the combinations. It is of size $4^3 + (3-1)$: that is, you're going to have to type in 66 letters to try every combination. The following will work:

dbdcbcbbbadcadbabacdacccdddcdccacbaaddadaacaaabdabcabbdbbcdbccbddb

No shorter sequence works. Indeed, there are 64 required subsequences to check, so you're going to need at least 66 letters.

Comment: Thank you very much! Would you mind telling me how you generated the sequence?

Comment: To be brutally honest: using Mathematica's function `DeBruijnSequence`. The Wikipedia page has an algorithm I might have used instead, or see the answer by gebra below.

Comment: Ah, got it. Thank you.